# Asterisk - restriction on number of extensions

Tags: asterisk

Is it possible to restrict number of extensions created in asterisk using sip.conf when asterisk is using realtime tables.

Comment: Let's say, from an asterisk we need only 100 extensions to be registered and if you are trying to created 1 more, it should not allow.

Answer (score 1):

Asterisk not create extensions.
It read extension from sip.conf, iax2.conf, realtime database etc

That files usually created by some web or control system(for example freepbx).

You should add restriction in your app/system which do add of extension.

There are no special limit on extensions number. Only limit like that is limit of concurrent channel count(controlled via asterisk.conf).

BUT asterisk is opensource soft. No any problem extend chan_sip, chan_iax2 etc to count extensions and load only first X extensions.