# Asterisk - extension Restriction

Tags: asterisk

**Is there a possibility in asterisk to restrict number of extensions. Let's say, from an asterisk we need only 100 extensions to be registered and if you are trying to created 1 more, it should not allow.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asterisk - restriction on number of extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38012168/asterisk-restriction-on-number-of-extensions)

Answer (score 0):

Its not a native functionality of asterisk but if you have some front end managing the real time user extensions then you can enable this functionality by customizing your front end application.